# Deriving forward Fokker-Planck equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-pde

I am struggling understanding the derivation of the forward Fokker-Planck equation from the Chapman-Kolmogorov equation. My book is very messy and I have wasted a lot of time with it. Could you please suggest me a source where I can find an easy and clearly explanation of the Fokker-Planck equation from the Chapman-Kolmogorov equation? I do not expect you to explain me it right now, just to give me a reference.
Thank you in advance!!

Comment: The proof uses a couple more assumptions; see Sec. 1.1 [here](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~shottovy/NumPDEreport.pdf).

Comment: You have tagged this as stochastic-pde. Is there a stochastic pde somewhere in your question?

Comment: @J.G. the link in your comment is no longer valid. Could you please update it?

Comment: @ric.san Good catch. [This](https://web.archive.org/web/20210413065745if_/http://www.math.wisc.edu/~shottovy/NumPDEreport.pdf) shouldn't rot.